# Associate custom objects with a particular user

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I am working on a Titanium Alloy project where in I am creating custom objects using ACS. I also have different users in the Users ACS. I wish to associate a particular custom object to a particular logged in user.

For example, If user A is logged in the custom object created by that user should be associated to user A. Same for user B and so on. How do I create this association? Currently my Custom objects get created but they are not associated to the logged in user.

After a little discussion, I realised I should add my scenario too.

My scenario is, a user changes a few settings using the toggle switch. This information should be stored for a user and later on push notification for selected settings should be sent to the user.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Shreerang

Answer (score 0):

So i think you should store custom object in database with its user name so whenever you want you can get back with user's name.

Comment: Its very simple.You can create one sqlite database and create one table with 2 columns.one is with username and another is with object as a field name and store your custom object as a text in object field with username.


How to work with database

->http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_Local_Data_Sources

Comment: Can I use this approach further to implement push notifications?

Comment: My scenario is, a user changes a few settings using the toggle switch. This information should be stored for a user and later on push notification for selected settings should be sent to the user.

Comment: yes, you can do that whatever you want to store it.